# Google Analytics Reporting API result count mismatch in php

Tags: php, google-analytics

Comparing with API results count is mismatch with Google Analytics report ( Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Source/Medium). I'm using below code to get this report in API.

```
function getReports($analytics) {      
    $VIEW_ID = "xxx";
    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("2020-01-18");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("2020-01-24");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");     

    $dimensions_source = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $dimensions_source->setName('ga:source');
    $dimensions_campaign = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $dimensions_campaign->setName('ga:campaign');
    $dimensions_medium = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $dimensions_medium->setName('ga:medium');
    $dimensions_dimension11 = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $dimensions_dimension11->setName('ga:dimension16');

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
    $request->setDimensions(array($dimensions_dimension11,$dimensions_source,$dimensions_medium,$dimensions_campaign));

    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
    return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}
```

Herewith I've attached the screenshot for Analytics UI view and API response. Counts are mismatched.

[image: Highlighted in Red color date and records count]

[image: Rowcount from API response is 3 only]

Assist me to figure out the issue.

Comment: please share output data from API and screenshot showing that indeed the exact same query produces different results

Comment: @Max edited the code and attached screenshots. please check